# Spring data and hibernate.. abstract class repository

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have an abstract generic base class, and im trying to use spring data jpa with hibernate to create a repository that allows me to fetch child classes...

as follows

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Vehicle")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="discriminator")
@DiscriminatorValue("ROOT")
public abstract class AbstractVehicle<
    D extends Engine, O extends Chassy>
    implements Model<D, O> {

....
...

}
```

I have two sub classes as follows:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("TRUCK")
public final class Truck<D extends TruckEngine> extends AbstractVehicle<D, TruckChassy>    {

..
..
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("CAR")
public final class Car<D extends CarEngine> extends AbstractVehicle<D, CarChassy> {

..
..
}
```

Now i am trying to use Spring Data JPA, to return me an object based on its id, then i want to to be able to do an instance of and, cast to the correct type... is that possible.. my interface for repository..

```
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public interface VehicleFinderRepository extends JpaRepository<AbstractVehicle, String> {
    }

}
```

All i am given is the id, and i know its going have base type of Vehicle, i want to do a fetch on the database and then get the type and cast afterwards.. When i run this i get cannot load entity Vehicle

Anyone got any ideas hot to go about this?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not wrong you do not want to have `@DiscriminatorValue("ROOT")` on `abstract class AbstractVehicle`

`@DiscriminatorColumn(name="discriminator")` will have either `Truck` or `CAR` values.